# Blackberry SDK - How to intercept PIN Messages to launch my Blackberry Application?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde, bb-messenger

I am just researching whether its possible.

1. I learned that using Blackberry SDK, from a blacbkerry app, we can send PIN messages to the user's contacts.
2. If the mail have a custom URL, we can use it to launch a Blackberry Application.

So my Question is whether

1. Can we launch a blackberry app from a Custom URL present in the PIN message?
2. Will we get the arguments in the Custom URL so that once launched we want to do something from inside the application?

Please help me. I am checking the possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible in a Java BlackBerry application.  The link below explains how and has a sample project that performs pattern matching to find US Zip Codes.

[Leverage pattern matching in BlackBerry smartphone applications to provide an integrated user experience](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Leverage-pattern-matching-in-BlackBerry-smartphone-applications/ta-p/445053)